# Social security number format missing under masking field format

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, data-masking

I implemented the dynamic data masking in my current project, for that I created the Azure SQL database and table. After that I went to dynamic data masking option in azure portal, then click on dynamic data masking option it will open snapshot like this below figure.

[image]

But in the above image there is no social security number format under masking field format.

How can I see the social security number format under masking field format option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After did R & D on how to mask the social security number in azure SQL database. I think Dynamic data masking provides for four different built in masking functions (default, Email, Custom String, and Random) see the below for more information.

**SQL Server 2016 New Features: Security and Encryption**

https://www.teamscs.com/2016/01/sql-server-2016-new-features-security-encryption/

That’s why we are not able see the social security number format under masking filed format option in Azure Portal.

So, I followed below link to implement the above concept.

**Dynamic Data Masking**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt130841.aspx

For Example:-

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerTables]
 ALTER COLUMN [SSN] ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(0,"XXX-XX-",4)');
```

Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Pradeep - indeed this is valid way to implement a relevant masking function for Social Security Numbers which exposes the last 4 digits. We currently don't support a built-in function that applies this format, though as you can see it is very easy to create such a format using the Custom string/ partial masking function.
Please do reach out if you have any additional questions.
Thanks!